# Is setInterval() and setTimeout() bad things to do in modern jQuery animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I had some problems with animations with jQuery 1.6. I solved it with jQuery 1.5.

In my project I used `setInterval()` to make custom logo slider. Animations fired up instantly (not simultaneously) two by two. Everything goes smoothly when I am on the page, but when I went on other tab and comeback (after minute, two or so) to my page project everything goes crazy...

Ok, so I got one answer to use `Queue()`. Can I achieve same thing with that method?

I have book Manning jQuery in Action and there is nothing on instantly fired up animations with `Queue()`.

[Link to Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dejancolic/Y5VdL/embedded/result/)

To quote some of that answer:

> Because of the nature of requestAnimationFrame(), you should never queue animations using a setInterval or setTimeout loop.

Comment: I had something similar happen on one of my pages. I solved it by `.stop()`ing all active animations at the beginning of each interval.

Comment: Different browsers handle timers differently with regard to what happens when your tab loses focus, e.g., some may temporarily suspend your `setInterval`; some may queue everything and then try to catch up when your tab gets focus again - sounds like this is what is happening to you.

Comment: @nnnnnn But with jQuery 1.5 there is no problem... I canceled UI effects and come back to `animate()`, but I suspect that will fix and UI effects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general **setInterval == BAD** and **setTimeout == GOOD** for animations.

**setInterval** will try play catchup, as **nnnnnn** stated:

> some browsers may queue everything and then try to catch up when your
>   tab gets focus again

You best method for looping animate() is by calling recursively, for example:

```
var myTimeout;

var myAnimation = function () {

    $('#myID').animate({
        [propertyKey]:[propertyValue]
    }, 5000, function() {
        myTimeout = setTimeOut(myAnimation, 1000);
    });
}
```

Notice how the **myTimeout** is held outside the scope of **myAnnimation** allowing the ability to stop the animation

```
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

Which you could hook up to the **window.unload** event.

Comment: Kinda, issue #9381 is the same window.unload problem, however using setInterval() will only exacerbate if further - You should always keep track of your animations. Unless you need a timer that plays catchup then setInterval is still evil.