# infinte loop while trying to display buffer symbol as pics preload

Tags: javascript, dom

I am really getting frustrated with this.  So I am making a slideshow with javascript but while all the images are being loaded I would like to show a buffering symbol..

here is the buffering symbol code.. if you have a better way of doing it please speak up.

```
function loadAnimation(){
        setTimeout(
            "document.getElementById('main_photo_img').src = 'images/loadBar1.jpg'", 300);
        setTimeout(
            "document.getElementById('main_photo_img').src = 'images/loadBar2.jpg'", 600);
        setTimeout(
            "document.getElementById('main_photo_img').src = 'images/loadBar3.jpg';", 900);
        }
```

that displays 3 images that make up a buffer animation.

my code for playing it until an image is loaded is this..

```
while(!pic1.onload){
    loadAnimation();
}
```

All that happens though is an infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you even need to have the `while`?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jHJeU/1/

Comment: an alternative is to load a loading graphic (small, cached, loads as DOM loads) and update it with the larger images after the page has loaded. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/a2LR5/ You can build a loading graphic at http://ajaxload.info. edit: I think I misread your question. The ajaxload.info site may help you greatly.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function loadAnimation() {
    var i = 0,
        timer;
    (function k() {
        var cur = i++ % 3 + 1;
        document.getElementById('main_photo_img').src = 'images/loadBar' + cur + '.jpg';
        timer = setTimeout(k, 300);
    })()
    return {
        cancel: function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    };
}


....

var animation = loadAnimation();
pic1.onload = animation.cancel; //The cancel will be called when pic1 loads. You may add other code in the cancel function if needed
```

I'd probably just use a gif or css background sprites, setting src dynamically is probably the hackiest way to do this I've seen to date ;p

Comment: Ok, I *think* I see what's going on; the OP is wanting to jerry rig a loading graphic?

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes I intepreted it as a way to show some loading bar animation while the image loads. Of course, it will never animate at all because the time between frames is 300ms, but meh :P

Comment: Whatever happened to just using a throbber?

Comment: could you elaborate on what makes it hacky?  why would css be a better way?  I am new to javascript so idk why it's wrong.  I wanna change an image src so it appears to be loading.

Comment: @Chris http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+sprite or make a separate question or search or use gif animations

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive setTimeout version which I think is what you're looking for.

```
var i = 0, intervalId;
function animate(){
    var newImg = 'images/loadBar' + ((i++ % 3) + 1) + '.jpg'
    document.getElementById('main_photo_img').src = newImg;
    intervalId = setTimeout(animate, 300);
}
```

And again, you'd stop this with

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

To start it with the first image showing up immediately you'd simply call

```
animate();
```

But to have the first image wait 300ms before showing, you would do

```
intervalId = setTimeout(animate, 300);
```

Comment: Not a fan of `setInterval()`, especially here. Better to set a new `setTimeout()` at the end of the last, in my opinion.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - why?  Wouldn't you have to keep recursively calling setTimeout each time?  Isn't this what setInterval is designed for?

Comment: Also, how is it canceled when the other event is finished (a picture loaded, I believe)?

Comment: Because `setInterval()` is not guaranteed to run at any interval except when the browser gets to it. It's just unreliable and should be avoided, IMO.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I did forget to include instructions for halting it.  So do "good" browsers like Chrome and FF handle setInterval well in your experience?  Or is it flawed across the board?

Comment: This probably explains it sufficiently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143043/451969 AFAIU, it's by just how JS works, since it's single-threaded.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, agree and there are many more arguments against [setInterval](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=setinterval+harmful). Also its much easier to work with setTimeouts in your code. setInterval is right up there with eval and array for..in.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - ok, I guess I learned something new today.  Answer is updated.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It was a wrinkle I didn't know about until a few months ago when somebody else pointed it out.