# Node.js setTimeout() behaviour

Tags: node.js

I want a piece of code to repeat 100 times with 1 sec of delay in between. This is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //do stuff
  },1000);
}
```

While this seems correct to me it is not. Instead of running "do stuff" 100 times and waiting 1 sec in between what it does is wait 1 sec and then run "do stuff" 100 times with no delay.

Anybody has any idea about this?

Comment: Why not setInterval with a counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it by using `setInterval()`.

It calls function of our choice as long as `clearTimeout` is called to a variable `timer` which stores it.

See example below with comments: (and remember to open your developer console (in chrome right click -> inspect element -> console) to view *console.log*).

```
// Total count we have called doStuff()
var count = 0;

/**
 * Method for calling doStuff() 100 times
 *
 */
var timer = setInterval(function() {

    // If count increased by one is smaller than 100, keep running and return
    if(count++ < 100) {
        return doStuff();
    }

    // mission complete, clear timeout
    clearTimeout(timer);

}, 1000); // One second in milliseconds

/**
 * Method for doing stuff
 *
 */
function doStuff() {
   console.log("doing stuff");
}
```

Here is also: **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ8Xa/3/)**

As a bonus: Your original method won't work because you are basically assigning 100 setTimeout calls as fast as possible. So instead of them running with one second gaps. They will run as fast as the for loop is placing them to queue, starting after 1000 milliseconds of current time.

For instance, following code shows timestamps when your approach is used:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){

    // Current time in milliseconds
    console.log(new Date().getTime()); 

  },1000);
}
```

It will output something like (milliseconds):

```
1404911593267 (14 times called with this timestamp...)
1404911593268 (10 times called with this timestamp...)
1404911593269 (12 times called with this timestamp...)
1404911593270 (15 times called with this timestamp...)
1404911593271 (12 times called with this timestamp...)
```

You can see the behaviour also in: **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ8Xa/2/)**

Comment: Oops, forgot to talk about the clearTimeout, +1 for you.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot for explaining why MY code did not work also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback, node.js is asynchronous:

```
function call_1000times(callback) {
var i = 0,

function do_stuff() {
    //do stuff
    if (i < 1000) {
        i = i + 1;
        do_stuff();
    } else {
        callback(list);
    }
}
do_stuff();
}
```

Or, more cleaner:

```
setInterval(function () {
    //do stuff
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you appreciate that the `for` loop is iterating in a matter of milliseconds, another way to do it would be to simply adjust the `setTimeout` delay according to the count.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){

  setTimeout(function(){

    //do stuff

  }, i * 1000);

}
```

For many use-cases, this could be seen as bad. But in particular circumstances where you know that you definitely want to run code *x* number of times after *y* number of seconds, it could be useful.

It's also worth noting there are [some that believe using `setInterval` is bad practise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143043/726766).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the recursive function. Call the function initially with the value of `counter` = 0, and then within the function check to see that `counter` is less than 100. If so, do your stuff, then call setTimeout with another call to `doStuff` but with a value of `counter + 1`. The function will run exactly 100 times, once per second, then quit :

```
const doStuff = counter => {
    if (counter < 100) {
        // do some stuff
        setTimeout(()=>doStuff(counter + 1), 1000)
    }
    return;
}
doStuff(0)
```