# Different behaviour of setTimeout in nodejs and Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code sample is -

```
global.a = 'aaa';

const obj = {
    a: 'a',
    desc() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}

setTimeout(obj.desc, 2000)
```

When I run this code in nodejs, I get the following output:

```
Timeout {
  _called: true,
  _idleTimeout: 2000,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 79,
  _onTimeout: [Function: desc],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 6,
  [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 1 }
undefined
```

But the same code, with `global` changed to `window` in Chrome/Firefox prints `aaa` and the `window` object, which is what this MDN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Explanation) says and which is what I expect.

I was under the impression that nodejs and Chrome both use Google's v8 JS engine to execute JavaScript. So why is the output different? Is there something more to this? I tried searching but couldn't find satisfactory answers.

Node version - v9.10.
Chrome's version - Version 70.0.3538.110

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'global' object in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627622/what-is-the-global-object-in-nodejs)

Comment: [Timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) are a very different beast under node.js. That both programs use the same JS engine doesn't mean they have to provide the same IO functionality.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653995/node-js-settimeout-behaviour Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, we must consult the source code for timers, since NodeJS' `setTimeout` and vanilla JS' `setTimeout` are not the same thing.

If we look [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L427), we will find the definition for `setTimeout`. We must pay attention to what happens with the callback that is passed in:

What happens is it is passed into the `Timeout` constructor:

```
const timeout = new Timeout(callback, after, args, false);
```

Ok, so what is the `Timeout` class? We can find that [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/timers.js#L75). Notice the line:

```
this._onTimeout = callback;
```

Ok, we stick the callback in an instance member, so I suspect that's how it is being called.

If we go back to the other source file and search for `_onTimeout`, we will find this line:

```
timer._onTimeout();
```

So in this case, because of how the callback is being called, `timer` is in fact what `this` refers to (as you've noted by logging `this` from the callback), and since the timer (or `Timeout` instance) does not have any such property (`a`), it logs `undefined`.

In vanilla JS, it behaves differently, and `this` refers to the `window` in your case.

As you may know, you can resolve this inconsistency by simply binding the callback to `obj` in `setTimeout` like so:

```
setTimeout(obj.desc.bind(obj), 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

node.js has its own implentation of timers which is different from browser implementations (although they can generally be used in the same way). This isn't really documented, but when you use `setTimeout`, it creates an instance of a `Timer` class with the callback passed as an argument. This callback is assigned to a property of the `Timer` instance which is used later:

- [Callback assigned as property of the Timer instance](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/timers.js#L75)
- [Callback called as instance function later](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js#L324)

This means that the `this` context for timers in node.js incidentally gets set to the Timer instance itself. Browsers apparently do something different.

This is mostly a semantic issue in your original code: when you pass function properties from objects they lose their context. You could use `.bind` to retain the context, or use another function to call `desc` directly on `obj` to retain the context.

```
setTimeout(obj.desc.bind(obj), 2000);
setTimeout(() => obj.desc(), 2000);
```

These two will log `obj` and `obj.a` in both node.js and browser environments.